# JavaScript: How can I transform objects array A to objects array B in the efficiency way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I got object array A as this:

```
[
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-01 00:00:00",
        "Label": "Voltage",
        "Value": "230.12"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-01 00:00:00",
        "Label": "Frequency",
        "Value": "50.12"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-01 00:00:00",
        "Label": "Power",
        "Value": "23"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-02 22:22:22",
        "Label": "Voltage",
        "Value": "231.12"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-02 22:22:22",
        "Label": "Frequency",
        "Value": "51.12"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-02 22:22:22",
        "Label": "Power",
        "Value": "23.4"
    }
]
```

I want to transform to object array B as this:

```
[
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-01 00:00:00",
        "Voltage": "230.12",
        "Frequency": "50.12",
        "Power": "23"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2015-10-02 22:22:22",
        "Voltage": "231.12",
        "Frequency": "51.12",
        "Power": "23.4"
    }
]
```

I was looping to get the timestamp and re-loop again to get label and value to form new object array. It works but when the data become few hundred thousands object array then it's not efficiency and crash the browser. Would someone can think of a better way please. Thanks very much.

Comment: Why are you putting together the data from different timestamps (2015-10-02 22:22:22 and 2015-10-02 00:00:00)?

Comment: Is your input sorted by timestamp? If yes, it's trivial to do in a single run.

Comment: pls explain your functionality more. How you making array B?

Comment: …and if not, a) sort it or b) use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to quickly look up the data.

Comment: there is no JSON, just javscript objects

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad, as you've provided no code in the question to show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and haven't asked a specific question that amounts to anything more than a work order.

Comment: It's actually a very specific question... voting to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is just a transport/storage format.  It's generally not something you should attempt to manipulate directly.  Best to manipulate the actual JavaScript objects/arrays.

If you can guarantee the original array sort order, try something like this:

```
var outputArray = [];
var currentObj = null;
originalArray.forEach(function (measurement) {
  if (!currentObj || currentTimestamp !== measurement.Timestamp) {
    currentTimestamp = measurement.Timestamp;
    currentObj = {
      Timestamp: measurement.Timestamp;
    }
    outputArray.push(currentObj);
  }
  currentObj[measurement.Label] = measurement.Value;
});
```

Then, you can just loop through and build the new array as you go.

Comment: Hi Brad, your also worked! Both of you and DAX scripts are better than mine, Thanks very much, I'll test it with hundred thousands of data today and let you guys know. Thanks again. https://jsfiddle.net/51r7onnm/

Comment: Surprisingly, using foreach and generic timestamp compare having much faster response than array.reduce method when I throw in hundred of thousands of datapoints with timestamp. And a b reduce looks very neat and straight forward! To be honest its quite advance for me when I see DAX use arrow function. Thank you very much! you guys are genius! I learnt a lot from yours snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As your desired output showed ignoring the time of the timestamp this will trim that part of the timestamp - if that was a mistake in the question I think you should be able to remove that part by yourself

```
var b = a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  var strippedTimestamp = cur.Timestamp.substring(1, 10) + " 00:00:00";
    var obj = acc.find(e => e.Timestamp == strippedTimestamp);
  if (!obj) {
    obj = { Timestamp: strippedTimestamp };
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  obj[cur.Label] = cur.Value;
  return acc;
}, []);
```

will output

```
[
    {
        "Timestamp": "015-10-01 00:00:00",
        "Voltage": "230.12",
        "Frequency": "50.12",
        "Power": "23"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "015-10-02 00:00:00",
        "Voltage": "230.12",
        "Frequency": "50.12",
        "Power": "23"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks DAX, your code work for me, except I removed the stripped timestamp. Sorry it was my typo mistakes about the timestamp, yes the machine return me each data point with timestamp but the front end display want to group them together by timestamp. https://jsfiddle.net/ow2d6f72/